# jQuery WeekPicker with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am trying to use jQuery datepicker in my Angular 2 application. In the **index.html** I have added

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Then I created a directive as below.

```
import {Directive, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
declare var $:JQueryStatic;
require('./jquery.weekpicker.js');

@Directive({
    selector: 'week-picker'
})
export class WeekPickerDirective {
    private htmlElement:HTMLElement;

    constructor(private element:ElementRef) {
        this.htmlElement = this.element.nativeElement;
        $(this.htmlElement).weekpicker();
    }

}
```

Then, in the **app.component.html** I have added the date picker as below.

```
<week-picker></week-picker>
```

In the **app.module.ts**

```
import {WeekPickerDirective} from "./shared/libs/weekpicker/week-picker.directive";

@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WeekPickerDirective
],
....
```

My **jquery.weekpicker.js**

```
(function($){
    var $calroot;

    function selectCurrentWeek() {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            var t = $calroot.find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a');//.addClass('ui-state-active');
            t= t.closest('tr');
            t.find('td>a').addClass('ui-state-active');//.parent().addClass('ui-state-active');
        }, 1);

    }
    function onSelect(dateText, inst) { 
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
        endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
        var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
        $calroot.trigger('weekselected',{
            start:startDate,
            end:endDate,
            weekOf:startDate
        });
        selectCurrentWeek();
    }
    var reqOpt = {
        onSelect:onSelect,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true
    };
    $.fn.weekpicker = function(options){
        var $this = this;
        $calroot = $this;

        $this.datepicker(reqOpt);
        //events
        $dprow = $this.find('.ui-datepicker');

        $dprow.on('mousemove','tr', function() { 
            $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); 
        });
        $dprow.on('mouseleave','tr', function() { 
            $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); 
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

When I try to build the app it says

```
ERROR in [default] ..\src\app\shared\libs\weekpicker\week-picker.directive.ts:15:28 
Property 'weekpicker' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.
```

Any suggestions ?

Thank You

Comment: Change declare var $:JQueryStatic; to declare var $ ; or declare var jQuery;

Comment: Error has gone & the project is build. But datepicker is not showing up

Comment: move  $(this.htmlElement).weekpicker(); part to ngAfterViewInit() { $(this.htmlElement).weekpicker();}

Comment: export class WeekPickerDirective implements AfterViewInit{
    private htmlElement:HTMLElement;
    constructor(private element:ElementRef) {
        this.htmlElement = this.element.nativeElement;
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        $(this.htmlElement).weekpicker();
    }
}

Comment: I tried above but no luck